# Implication of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to ask whether the following statement is true or not:

> $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a(n)=0$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a(n)b(n)=1$ implies that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|b(n)|=\infty$

I would like to check my solution. I came to the conclusion that the implication holds.

Comment: You’ll find a basic MathJax reference guide and tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference); if you plan to post here, you’ll want to learn to use MathJax to write mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Step: Show that $b_n$ cannot be bounded. Suppose your statement is not true.
   What can you say?
2. Step: You must indeed have $|b_n| \to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

I strongly encourage you not to view all steps at once but rather try for yourself.

1. Step:

> Suppose there is an $M > 0$ such that $|b_n| \leq M$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

> Now $|a_nb_n| \leq |a_n|M$.

> Hence $|a_n b_n| \leq |a_n| M \to 0$, meaning $a_nb_n \to 0 \neq 1$ as $n\to\infty$.

2. Step:

> You already know that $b_n$ cannot be bounded. All that is left to do is to show that for any possible bound $M>0$ there would be an index $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|b_n| \geq M$ for all $n\geq N$. It is not possible that you have a subsequence that is bounded.

> If this was not true, you would (for some fixed $M>0$) find $n_1$ such that $b_{n_1} \leq M$. By using $N=n_1+1$ you would get an $n_2 > n_1$ such that $b_{n_2} \leq M$.

> Iterating this argument would give you $n_1 < n_2 < \ldots$ such that $|b_{n_k}| \leq M$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

> But this would mean $|a_{n_k}b_{n_k}| \leq |a_{n_k}|M \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, contradicting $a_nb_n \to 1$.

More generally, $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_nb_n = c \neq 0$ would imply the same result by the exact same arguments.

**Edit:** The arguments from Step 2 should already suffice as a proof, making Step 1 superfluous but nevertheless i think it's good to think about Step 1 separately to get an intuition for the problem, since in Step 2 we refine the argument from Step 1.